# What are some of the uses of the invariant spacetime interval?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, invariants

I am currently researching special relativity and I have come across the invariant interval. So far, I know that all observers will measure the same interval regardless of position or velocity, and its invariance under a Lorentz transformation can be proven algebraically. However, I am struggling to find actual, real-world uses of the interval, which would be very interesting to me. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The Euclidean analogue of your question is "What are some uses of the length (or square-length) of a line segment on the plane?"

In special relativity, one uses a spacetime diagram, with the underlying Minkowski metric.

The time dilation problem is essentially relating
"the spacetime interval (the elapsed proper time) along a straight worldline segment from event A to event B"
with 
"the temporal-component of the spacetime-displacement vector AB",
as function of the relative velocity.

In dynamics problems,
one could be interested in the "invariant mass of a particle",
given (say) the temporal (ie Energy) and spatial (Momentum) components of the 4-momentum, as measured in a given frame.

Answer (score 1):

This is my favourite; the Twins "Conundrum":

Stay-at-home twin:
$$d\tau^2 = dt^2 - dx^2 = dt^2$$
$$d\tau = dt$$

Traveling twin ($0.8c$), there & back:
$$d\tau^2 = dt^2 - dx^2 = dt^2 - 0.64dt^2 = 0.36dt^2$$
$$d\tau = 0.6dt$$

Notice in particular that acceleration is *not* involved in that calculation, *nor* is it necessary to specify the actual distance traveled.

Comment: This could maybe be summarized as follows: if two events are timelike seperated (distance in time is bigger than distance in space) the spacetime interval gives the proper time. If they are spacelike separarated (distance in space is bigger than distance in time) the spacetime interval gives the proper length.